# Resetting multiple states with react redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

In my app I've got multiple Steps, which each have their very own state and I want to have a link that fires an onClick Action that resets all of these states back to their initial value. Sadly I'm having problems doing exactly that.

First I have this Nav in which I call my `resetHandler()` function, in which I would like to have the reset action:

```
<StageNavigation
        resetHandler={() => {
          history.push(routes.EVENTS.path)
          // right now it only takes the users back one step, but I also want it to reset all states
        }}
      />
```

I tried to search for a solution on that and the most used "solution" to all this was something like that:

```
export default rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === LOGOUT) {
    state = undefined;
  }

  return appReducer(state, action);
};
```

Now in my `index.ts` (we use typescript, if this is an important information) I have tried something similar:

```
const appReducer = combineReducers({
  events,
  registrations,
  program,
  institution,
  misc,
  paymentData,
  participant,
})


const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
      // what action can I give it? Should I even give it an action?
      state = undefined
      return appReducer(state, action)
    };

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware({
    serializableCheck: {
      ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
    },
  }),
})

const persistor = persistStore(store)

export default store

export { persistor, rootReducer, appReducer }
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>
export type AppThunk = ThunkAction<void, RootState, null, Action<string>>
```

The problem is that I don't really know what action I could give the rootReducer or if I even would need one? Then also how would I call this in my `resetHandler()` and how would I be able to give it the state and action needed to completely reset everything?

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to change the values kept at the Redux store, **you'll definitely need an action**. Let's call it `RESET_VALUES`, for example. By using this action type, the `rootReducer` you wrote as an example should do the trick:

```
export default rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === RESET_VALUES) {
    state = undefined;
  }

  return appReducer(state, action);
};
```

Once you've done that, **you just have to dispatch this new `RESET_VALUES` action from your `resetHandler` method**. You'll dispatch it as you would any other action, nothing special about this one.

When the reset action is triggered, **all of the reducers will run and set their state to the default parameter you assigned to their `state` argument**. If you haven't specified any, `undefined` will be used instead.

To ensure your reducers get the right value on reset, make sure that all of your reducers have their initial state set as a default value for the `state` parameter. This is important if you want to preserve some kind of structure, such as in this example:

```
const initialState = {
  itemList: [],
  selectedItem: null
};

function itemReducer (state = initialState, action) { ... }
```

In this case, you want your reducer to always return an object with a predefined structure. If you fail to add `initialState` as a default value for the `state` parameter, your data structure will be lost during reset.

Anyway, be careful with this here:

```
const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  state = undefined
  return appReducer(state, action)
};
```

Keep in mind that **any action you trigger will be automatically received by all of the reducers**. This means anytime you trigger an action anywhere, your `rootReducer` is also being called. Since you're not filtering by action type here, you're deleting the whole state anytime an action is dispatched. Because of this, make sure that you wrap `state = undefined` in an `if` block like in the example above, so that line of code is not executed unless you're indeed trying to perform a reset.